# Responsive css issue (Foundation framework)

Tags: html, css, wordpress, zurb-foundation

This might be a silly question, I am quite confident in CSS and am starting to learn more about Javascript, essentially I am trying to fix more problems myself rather than relying on my freelance programmer however I have become a bit stumped.

If you visit http://www.giftshuffle.co.uk and minimise the screen down to mobile size, the titles start to pull away from the images. 
The site is using foundation framework for responsiveness.

Any idea? Where I should be looking?

Thanks
Oliver

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: How can I stop the title from moving away from the image, essentially the element is staying the same width but growing in height.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[media queries](http://mediaqueri.es/)** for responsive design.

For your case add below code in css:

```
@media screen and (max-width:740px){

   #teaser-image
     {
       width:100%;
     }
}
```